# What is the difference between PHONE NUMBER & NUMERIC TEXT inputtype in android text fields?

Tags: layout, android, keyboard

I'm designing a keyboard application for android. Came across the various [input types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) such as - phone number, email, url, etc. for which the keyboard should ideally change layout for the user.

I couldn't understand the difference between `NUMBER` & `PHONE`.

`PHONE` - I get it, is used to input phone numbers which can have: 0-9, plus, hashtag, hyphen, asterisk & brackets.

`NUMBER` - ??

I couldn't find any text fields which specifically uses `NUMBER` as their input type. So where exactly is it used? And what should the keyboard layout have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least a couple of reasons why the two fields are different - One for the user and one for the developer/site owner.

The 'number' field will, when focussed on a mobile device, trigger a simplified number keypad with the numbers 1-9, a '-', a',', a '.', and a '_'. Whereas the 'phone' field will trigger a telephone-style keypad that also includes '#', '*' and '+' as well as the letter groups you find on a regular phone dial pad.

The differences are also useful for data management operations where the fields will be passed to the server as 'number=""' or 'phone=""'.

You can try with your own devices at http://nativeformelements.com